# JQuery delegate 'on' click does not work on newly added content with angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Basic HTML page with an angular app that loops through my controller scope's array and with the help of ng-repeat prints the array content as navigation.

```
        <div ng-app="FilterApp">
        <div class="regionMenu" ng-controller="myRegionCtrl">
        <a href="#" data-target="#regionItems" data-toggle="collapse" style="color:black;"><i class="fa fa-list mt"></i><span class="collapse in hidden-xs">{{ selected.name }}<span class="caret"></span></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked collapse" id="regionItems">
                <li ng-click="setNewRegion(region)" ng-repeat="region in regions">
                    <a href="" title="{{ region.id }}">{{ region.name }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The problem arises when I try to add to each ***li a*** a jquery on click listener function< I tried possibly every combination I could think off to make it work, example: ***.regionMenu li a***, etc but to no avail.

```
$(document).on("click", "li a", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("title");
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("MyApp working..." + id);
});
```

But the above code does print when it's the case of ***li a***, but li a is too broad. I don't want every list anchor element on my page to work the same way. thanks~!

Comment: perhaps place a class name for your a tag?

Comment: And its not `.delegate()` is the Content already loaded when u add the eventlistener?

Comment: Try this "ul.nav li a"

Comment: Could you post a live example in jsfiddle or jsbin.com

Comment: Thank you very much guys and thank you @Luminous_Dev much much appreciated `<a class="regionz" href="" title="{{ region.id }}">{{ region.name }}</a>` I placed a class name for my anchor tag and now it works.